# Should I use Google Cloud Storage or Unlimited Google Drive for Tiktok clone app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I'm going to use serverless structure to build a Tiktok's clone app. 
I'm using Firebase function for backend.
I want to ask should I use Google Cloud Storage to store user's uploaded videos or using Unlimited Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Cloud Storage as you would pay only for the amount of data you are storing and you would be able to use a [lifecycle policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to manage your objects in the buckets.

Also, if you are already using Firebase, it would be easy to integrate Cloud Storage your functions.

Hope you find this information useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any example that using Google Cloud Storage for upload video and load it on application like Facebook watch or Tiktok? Because I could not find one!